# How is it possible to have feeds from different Urls in the same ListView

Tags: android, listview, url, feed

With my current project I can take datas from a single Url and then display them in my Custom Listview.
So is there a way I can get datas from more than one Url and then put in the same ListView even if the datas from each Url are called differently?
This is my code that allows me to have the items from a URL:

```
    public  class CLASS1 extends Fragment {

    private RSSFeed myRssFeed = null;

    public CLASS1()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, null);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        try {
            URL rssUrl = new URL("URL");
            SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();
            RSSHandler myRSSHandler = new RSSHandler();
            myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);
            InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
            myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);

            myRssFeed = myRSSHandler.getFeed();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        if (myRssFeed!=null)
        {
            ListView list = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            CustomList adapter = new CustomList(getActivity(),myRssFeed.getList());
            adapter.addAll();
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Spiacente, connessione non disponibile!" +
                            " Prova più tardi.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am exactly doing this in my app,

This is how i am doing this, I have created `AsyncTask` to parse RSS, and using a loop to pass different URLs to be parsed to `AysncTask`.

Here is what I mean,

This is the array of URL,

```
private String[] newsURLs = {
            "url1", "url2", "url3" };
```

this is how I am executing them,

```
//GetNews is AsyncTask class
for (int i = 0; i < newsURLs.length; i++) {
                GetNews blog = new GetNews(i);
                blog.execute();
            }
```

In the above code `i`is the URL number passed in as a constructor in `AsyncTask` class.

Here is my constructor in `AsyncTask` class,

```
int number;
public GetNews(int urlNumber) {
            number = urlNumber;
        }
```

and loading the URL in `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground()` method this way,

```
                URL feedURL = new URL(newsURLs[number]);
                HttpURLConnection connection;
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) feedURL.openConnection();
                connection.setConnectTimeout(8000);
                connection.connect();
```

After that, I am using `SAXParser` to parse `xml` based on my need.

Please note that if you want parallel execution, replace `blog.execute();` 
with

```
blog.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

// this type of executor uses the following params:
            //
            // private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = 5;
            // private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = 128;
            // private static final int KEEP_ALIVE = 1;
            //
            // private static final ThreadFactory sThreadFactory = new ThreadFactory() {
            //     private final AtomicInteger mCount = new AtomicInteger(1);
            //
            //     public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            //         return new Thread(r, "AsyncTask #" + mCount.getAndIncrement());
            //     }
            // };
            //
            // private static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> sPoolWorkQueue =
            //        new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10);
```

Also note that,

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting
>   with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple
>   tasks to operate in parallel.
>   After HONEYCOMB, it is planned to change this back to a single thread
>   to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution. If
>   you truly want parallel execution, you can use the
>   executeOnExecutor(Executor, Params...) version of this method with
>   THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR; however, see commentary there for warnings on
>   its use.

DONUT is Android 1.6, HONEYCOMB is Android 3.0.

You may also execute the task based on what version you have,

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    blog.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
} else {
    blog.execute();
}
```

This is my partial code to show what I am doing,

```
    // This is my Main class

private String[] newsURLs = {
            "url1", "url2", "url3" };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_myapp);


            for (int i = 0; i < newsURLs.length; i++) {
                GetNews blog = new GetNews(i);
                blog.execute();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is `AsyncTask` class (partial code),

```
private class GetNews extends
        AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {

    protected int number;

    public GetNews(int urlNumber) {
        number = urlNumber;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(
            Object... arg0) {

        try {
            // Check if the feed is Live
            URL feedURL = new URL(newsURLs[number]);
            HttpURLConnection connection;
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) feedURL.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(8000);
            connection.connect();
```

Comment: I am using a RSS Handler that is able to take the item from an URL and then display it in my Listview. How does this code work for you?

Comment: I am doing the same thing except that I am using SAXparser to parse RSS according to my needs and then displaying them in a ListView, I am parsing 4 XML feeds and displaying them in one list without any problem.

Comment: The problem I got with _Yahoo Pipes_ was that the items from the URLs were called differently ( for example the images in one were in _<img src="...">_ while in another were in _<enclosure url="...">_ . So did you create more Hanlders?

Comment: I simply applied if/else condition that switch the item name based on  which url is currently being parsed.

Comment: One more thing: with this method how do I get the news? Are the items sorted by _pub.Date_ in ascending order automatically?

Comment: The method i mentioned above is just to execute multiple tasks, I didn't include code to parse XML after URL is loaded. btw, items in rss are already sorted by date so you shouldn't be worried about that.

Comment: Okay, I'll try this and I'll let you know :D Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: You have created instance of AsyncTask class inside itself instead of the main class. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Now I edited again but you said: _This is AsyncTask class (partial code)_ . What is the other part of AsyncTask? Is it a class of its own?

Comment: Hello, there is onPostExecute() method and there is other part responsible for parsing xml feeds and then storing it in a ListView and updating ListView everytime new Feed from different url is added in a ListView. 
I would like to mention that I have already answered your question but I cannot provide you the entire solution.

Comment: No of course, you're right. I really appreciate your help on this and I hope I can finish my app in your way and get the news with AsyncTask. I give you the 50 of the bounty and a vote up ;)

Comment: go ahead and raise another question if you face any issue. :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I faced another problem after I added _onPostExecute()_ method. The code is good so as the Urls but I keep getting the Toast message. I invite you to take a look at my other question: _http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27643157/issue-with-getting-feed-data-with-asynctask/27646154?noredirect=1#comment43723941_27646154_ .
Sorry again :D